# Passing WebElement as parameter to implicit wait method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

I wrote the below method in my Page.class for reusing implicit wait.

```
public WebDriver waitForElementToLoad(WebElement element)
{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By) element));
        return (driver);
}
```

In my test.class I am using page factory elements, for example:

```
//Save button
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@*='Save']")
private WebElement saveButton;
```

Now I am trying to call:
`waitForElementToLoad(saveButton);` 
from test.Class but I am getting below error.

> "java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12 cannot be
>   cast to class org.openqa.selenium.By (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12 and
>   org.openqa.selenium.By are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"

I also tried

```
WebElement saveButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@*='Save']"));
waitForElementToLoad(saveButton);
```

but no luck.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

`WebDriverWait` is explicit wait, not implicit. And you can't cast `WebElement` to `By`.

If `saveButton` is not `null` than it was already found by the page factory, waiting for it presence is meaningless, that's why you don't have an overload with `WebElement`. Wait for  visibility instead

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

Comment: This works, Thanks. Now if I have a dynamic xpath like: 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='profile-link-label' and text()='"+userName+"'])[1]"));

and I want to pass it as parameter to the same method. How can I do that?

Comment: @user194258 You need to send the `WebElement` returned, or build a new method that receive `By` instead of web element and use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//a[@class='profile-link-label' and text()='"+userName+"'])[1]"))`

Comment: For the new method that receive By, what will be the datatype if it's not WebElement?
Also, when I send the parameter, should I be sending driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@class='profile-link-label' and text()='"+userName+"'])[1]")); or just (//a[@class='profile-link-label' and text()='"+userName+"'])[1]") ?

Comment: @user194258 You send `By`, `By.xpath("...")`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `ExpectedConditions` with some your "Page" class that contains asynchronously loaded elements I would recommend to use the following approach:

1. Extend `AjaxElementLocator` where override `protected boolean isElementUsable(WebElement element)` so that it uses `ExpectedConditions` to decide if the element is ready for use
2. Extend `AjaxElementLocatorFactory` where override `public ElementLocator createLocator(Field field)` method so that it now returns the instance of your extended class
3. Where you initialize elements use `PageFactory.initElements(new MyAjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 10), this);` where `MyAjaxElementLocatorFactory` is the class that you created on step 2

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12 cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.By (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12 and org.openqa.selenium.By are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

...implies that the *ClassCastException* occured while trying to cast a **proxy** object.

You need to consider a few things as follows:

- The wait you introduced within `waitForElementToLoad()` isn't [implicit wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706) as such but an [ExplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706693/how-to-combine-implicit-and-explicit-timeouts-in-selenium/52707885#52707885). See: [What is the internal working difference between Implicit Wait and Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365040/what-is-the-internal-working-difference-between-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait/46398760#46398760)
- `presenceOfElementLocated()` doesn't garuntees the *visibility* or *interactablity* of any element. So for *visibility* or *interactablity* you need to use the matching ExpectedConditions either `visibilityOf(WebElement element)` or `elementToBeClickable(By locator)`. For details, see: [Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165)
- If your usecase involves inducing *WebDriverWait* you pass the *WebElement* **saveButton** in the form of a *proxy* object within `waitForElementToLoad()` as follows:

  ```
  package com.pol.zoho.PageObjects;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class ZohoLoginPage {

      WebDriver driver;
      public ZohoLoginPage(WebDriver driver)
      {
      PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }

      //Save button
      @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@*='Save']")
      private WebElement saveButton;

      public void waitForElementToLoad()
      {
      WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ZohoLoginPage.getWebElement()));
      saveButton.click();
      }

      public WebElement getWebElement()
      {
      return saveButton;
      }

  }
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to add explicit wait in PageFactory in PageObjectModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158166/how-to-add-explicit-wait-in-pagefactory-in-pageobjectmodel/54177337#54177337)
- [How to wait for invisibility of an element through PageFactory using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669417/how-to-wait-for-invisibility-of-an-element-through-pagefactory-using-selenium-an/54670978#54670978)