# How to handle alert message within PageObjects

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

Code trials:

```
package Pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
public class pageBase {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public pageBase(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    public static void AcceptAlert() {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
}
```

Test page:

```
public void SignUp(String user_name,String password) throws InterruptedException {
    Set_UserName(user_name);
    Set_Password(password);
    click_SignupBtn();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    AcceptAlert();
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.switchTo()" because "Pages.pageBase.driver" is null
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the *`pageBase`* pageobject as you are casting the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) instance you need to remove the keywords:

- *public*
- *static*

Effectively, instead of:

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

your line of code will be:

```
WebDriver driver;
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to wait for invisibility of an element through PageFactory using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54670978/7429447)

Comment: i tried it and doesn't work